# Overriding bootstrap typeahead css class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I need to override `.typeahead` css class of bootstrap typeahead functionality however I need to keep the default.

Usually, I wrap the such classes with a div with some custom class and override it like

```
.my-class .typeahead{...}
```

However, bootstrap creates an `ul` dynamically so I couldn't apply such wrapper.

What could be the solution for it?

Answer (score 4):

The Bootstrap Typeahead dropdown dynamically generates the following HTML:

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">
  ...
  <li><a href="#">MATCHING RESULT</a></li>
  ...
```

The default CSS rule that applies is also the one styling drop down menus.

```
.dropdown-menu .active > a,
.dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
color: #333333;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #0081c2;
...
}
```

So to override the typeahead without changing the drop down menu, you'll need to add a rule somewhere after this one. I place mine in a separate file after I load the bootstrap.css.*

```
.typeahead .active > a,
.typeahead .active > a:hover {
color: white;

/* Change the typeahead background color here if you'd like */
background-color: Green;

/* Turns off the default background gradients */
background-image: none;
}
```

*Best practice recommends that you combine and minimize all CSS when you go to production, but regardless, this rule should be after the one above unless you make it more specific than the .dropdown-menu rule

Comment: But it overrides bootstrap typeahead. I need to change the width of typeahead class for only one special input but others should be same as before

Comment: Then give that special input a class and style it.